# bad result: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined at prune error when deploying code from the Trailhead

Tags: lightning-web-components, trailhead

I am trying to finish a Communicate Between Unrelated Components Trailhead, however when I deploy the `default` folder, I get a following error in the Deployment Status:

```
`bad result: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined at prune 
             (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.17.9-232.0/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-compiler/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-metadata/dist/template/transform/binding.js:112:17) 
             at getPrunedPath (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.17.9-232.0/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-compiler/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-metadata/dist/template/transform/binding.js:122:12) 
             at /home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.17.9-232.0/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-compiler/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-metadata/dist/template/transform/binding.js:196:28 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) 
             at Object.transform (/home/sfdc/tools/lwc/1.17.9-232.0/node_modules/@lwc-platform/sfdc-lwc-compiler/node_mo`
```

How to fix this? All files seem to be fine, the HTML file has also one main `template` tag. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Sadly, no. Updating SFDX also has no effect on this.

Comment: try debugging sfdx as outlined in the post